# Proving $V(\mathbb{F}_q)=\{ P \in V :\varphi(P)=P\}$, when $\varphi$ is the Frobenius map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and let $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

The $q^{th}$ power map $\varphi: = [ X_0^q , . . . , X_n^q ]$ is a morphism $\varphi: V\to V$. It is called the Frobenius morphism.

I would like to prove that $V(\mathbb{F}_q)=\{ P \in V :\varphi(P)=P\}$.

I know absolute projective plane over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is characterized as fixed points of action by absolute Galois group over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (this proof needs Hilbert theorem 90).

Any other proof (not using above fact) is also appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The definition of a $K$-point is a point $P \in V$ such that $\sigma(P) = P$ for all $\sigma \in G_K$ (the absolute galois group). For $\mathbb{F}_q$ the frobenius is a topological generator for $G_{\mathbb{F}_q}$, hence $P \in V$ if and only if it is fixed by the frobenius.

Comment: If we define K-rational point of V to be V∩P^n（K）, we need to use Hilbert theorem 90 to caractarlize K-rational point as invariant of action by absolute Galois group?

Comment: Well I would say that $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ is the set of $P \in \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\sigma(P) = P$ for all $\sigma \in G_K$... so if you want a better answer you will need to ask a better question i.e., how do you define a $K$-point